# Using shell globbing with Ansible templates

Tags: shell, ansible

Is it a way to use shell globing to specify several files as a `src` in template module?

```
- name: Copy keys    
  template:    
    src: "{{ item }}"/RPM-*     
    dest: /etc/pki/{{ item }}/
  loop:
    - gf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ansible's [`fileglob` loookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/fileglob.html)to do this. You would pass in your patterns as a list of arguments to `with_fileglob`, like this (rather than putting the pattern in the `src` argument of the `template` module):

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Copy keys
      template:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "./pki/{{ '/'.join(item.split('/')[-2:]) }}"
      with_fileglob:
        - "gf/RPM-*"
        - "xz/RPM-*"
```

This copies files into `./pki/gf/RPM-...` and `./pki/xz/RPM-...`. The expression `'/'.join(item.split('/')[-2:])` takes a pathname like `/some/path/to/gf/RPM-foo` and transforms it into `gf/RPM-foo`.

Note that you need to ensure the target directories exist first, which is probably going to require a separate task preceding this one to create them.

Comment: I'd love a comment to go along with that -1!

Comment: (downvoting trolls, nevermind...)